# add class to <tr> depending on xml data

Tags: jquery, html, xml, addclass

This is my html

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th colspan="4" align="center">Course 1</th>
        <th colspan="4" align="center">Course 2</th>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">Course 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Region</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>KO</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="data1">
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is my Jquery to parse data from xml to HTML

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.xml", 
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
    alert('Connected to XML');      
        $(xml).find('test').each(function(){
            var Col1 = $(this).find('Region').text();
            var Col2 = $(this).find('User').text();
            var Col3 = $(this).find('Time').text();
            var Col4 = $(this).find('Test').text();
            var Col5 = $(this).find('KO').text();
            $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>'+Col1+'</td><td>'+Col2+'</td><td>'+Col3+'</td><td>'+Col4+'</td><td>'+Col5+'</td>').appendto('#data1');
```

I would like to be able to assign a class to a row depending on the data from the xml (Region) for instance.

if region=asia add class "blue" 
if region=europe add class "pink"

is this something i can add to my above Jquery? please advise

is this possible? Thanks in advance for any suggestions or methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated, the following code is one way of doing it:

```
if (Col1 === 'asia')  $('<tr class="blue"></tr>').html('<td>'+Col1+'</td><td>'+Col2+'</td><td>'+Col3+'</td><td>'+Col4+'</td><td>'+Col5+'</td>').appendTo('#data1');

else if (Col1 === 'europe')  $('<tr class="pink"></tr>').html('<td>'+Col1+'</td><td>'+Col2+'</td><td>'+Col3+'</td><td>'+Col4+'</td><td>'+Col5+'</td>').appendTo('#data1');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/gmLokr0n/) (note it hasn't been tested with XML data). Also you need to change your `appendto` function call to [.appendTo()](https://www.google.fi/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jquery%20appendto) (with capital 'T').

Comment: @Gawai Excellent. I'm glad that I was able to help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `switch` based on the text you get.

As we know from your code, you have a reference to the region here: `var Col1 = $(this).find('Region').text();`

So, try something like this:

```
var className = "";

switch(Col1){
    case: "asia" :
        className = "asia-class";
        break;
    case: "europe" :
        className = "europe-class";
        break;
}
```

Later you could use that `className` variable like this:

`$('<tr></tr>').addClass(className).html('<td>'+Col1+'</td><td>'+Col2+'</td><td>'+Col3+'</td><td>'+Col4+'</td><td>'+Col5+'</td>').appendto('#data1');`